# app script for locking cell after data was inputted

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script

I am currently making reservation calendar and I want to locked cell after they inputted information on specific columns.
More or less 10 columns to have that function. I Really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: are you using google sheets, java, or excel. Your question doesn't state that. Also please show us the code you've written and where that needs improvement.

Comment: If you are using excel, have a look at `Worksheet_Change` event. It should give you a good start

Comment: google sheets. Is it easier to locked cell with input data after saving the file. Can you help me how.. Thank you.

Comment: Is it Apps Script or App Engine ?

Answer (score 0):

This is right out of the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()).

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
 var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
```

Comment: is theres a way to autolocked inputted cell after saving the google doc???